# For loop over a List of Data frames

Tags: r, for-loop

I'm using the mtcars dataset in R. I have a list of data frames (mtcars dataset split into number of cylinders). I need to:

1. Identify the car with the min value for miles per gallon (mpg) within each cylinder type (i.e. 4,6,8).
2. Create a vector that stores the values of horsepower (hp) for each of the cars found in step 1 (the length of the vector will be 3).

Steps I have performed so far, as follows:

```
# load the data
data(mtcars)

# split cars data.frame into a list of data frames by cylinder
cars <- split(mtcars, mtcars$cyl)    

# find the position within each data frame for the min values of mpg (i.e. first 
# column)
positions <- sapply(cars,function(x) which.min(x[,1]))
```

As I see it, the next step would be to make a loop over each data frame to find the horsepower value for each position. I have tried to make a For loop for this, but I haven't been able to make it work. Maybe there's even a better solution for this problem.

Comment: Note @bstockton points out something important in the answer comments.  There are two cars sharing the minimum value in the 8cyl category.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to `split` the data and then use `sapply`. There are many ways to reach that output using much more efficient ways. Here's possible `data.table` solution

```
mtcars$Cars <- rownames(mtcars)
library(data.table)
data.table(mtcars)[, list(Car = Cars[which.min(mpg)],
                           HP = hp[which.min(mpg)]),
                   by = cyl]

#    cyl                Car  HP
# 1:   6          Merc 280C 123
# 2:   4         Volvo 142E 109
# 3:   8 Cadillac Fleetwood 205
```

Or maybe using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>% 
  mutate(Cars = rownames(mtcars)) %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>% 
  summarize(Car = Cars[which.min(mpg)], HP = hp[which.min(mpg)]) 

# Source: local data frame [3 x 3]
# 
#   cyl                Car  HP
# 1   4         Volvo 142E 109
# 2   6          Merc 280C 123
# 3   8 Cadillac Fleetwood 205
```

Comment: There are two cars which have the same minimum value for mpg in the 8 cylinder category.

Answer (score 1):

From the pre-split `cars` set, you can do it this way with `Map` and `Reduce`.

```
> Reduce(rbind,  
         Map(function(x) x[which.min(x$mpg), "hp", drop = FALSE],   
             cars, USE.NAMES = FALSE)  
         )
                     hp
# Volvo 142E         109
# Merc 280C          123
# Cadillac Fleetwood 205
```

If you wanted a vector, you can assign the above code to a variable, say `rr`, and do

```
> setNames(rr[,1], rownames(rr))
#        Volvo 142E          Merc 280C Cadillac Fleetwood 
#               109                123                205
```

Answer (score 1):

This is really easy if you use the plyr library. Here ya go:

```
library(plyr)
data(mtcars)

mpMins <- ddply(mtcars, .(cyl),summarize, min = min(mpg), .drop = FALSE)
mpMins

    cyl  min
1   4 21.4
2   6 17.8
3   8 10.4
```

This only gives you the minimum value of the mpg though, you want the horsepower too

```
hpMins <- (merge(mpMins, mtcars, by.x = c("min","cyl"), by.y = c("mpg","cyl" )))$hp
hpMins
[1] 205 215 123 109
```

Strange, there are four values. You said you wanted three. If you go back and check the data though, there are two minimum values of 10.4 for the 8 cylinder category. Remember to be careful when going to summary values (like minimums) to individual observations.